# Attached program is giving an output, even if conditions are not met

Tags: labeling, conditional

```
(Label["top"];
{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h} = Abs[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0,1],8]];
nu0 = ToExpression[ToString[NumberForm[a*b, 2]]];  
nu1 = ToExpression[ToString[NumberForm[c*d, 2]]];  
nu2 = ToExpression[ToString[NumberForm[e*f, 2]]];
nu3 = ToExpression[ToString[NumberForm[g*h, 2]]];
If[nu0 != nu1 || nu2 != nu3, Goto["top"]]);
Print[{nu0, nu1}, {nu2, nu3}];
```

Attached program is supposed to give the result,
if nu0 = nu1, and nu2
= nu3 simulteneously, But Most of the times,
if gives an output even 
if nu0 != nu1, Please run this program until you notice the same problem.
Please Help ??

Comment: You can see the corrections [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/157988/revisions)

Comment: @Coolwater Thank Man :)